# Recorrer un input y reemplazar letras por numeros en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Copio el código que estoy armando:

```py
#-----Comienzo-----

nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")

vocales = "a, e, i, o, u"

letrasVocales = ""

consonantes = "b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, ñ, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z"

letrasConsonantes = ""

#-----Diccionario-----

letas = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "j": 2,
    "s": 2,
    "k": 2,
    "t": 3,
    "l": 3,
    "d": 3,
    "u": 4,
    "m": 4,
    "e": 5,
    "x": 5,
    "p": 5,
    "n": 6,
    "ñ": 6,
    "f": 6,
    "y": 6,
    "w": 7,
    "o": 7,
    "g": 7,
    "h": 8,
    "r": 8,
    "z": 8,
    "q": 9,
    "i": 9,
    }

#-----Extraer vocales-----

for i in nombre:

    if i in vocales:
        letrasVocales += i

listaVocales = list (letrasVocales)

print (listaVocales)


#-----Extraer consonantes-----

for i in nombre:

    if i in consonantes:
        letrasConsonantes += i

listaConsonantes = list (letrasConsonantes)

print (listaConsonantes)


#-----Recorrer las listas para reemplazar las letras por el numero del diccionario-----
```

A partir de este punto, no se cómo continuar. Necesito poder recorrer cada una de las listas listaConsonantes  y listaVocales para asignarles a cada uno de las letras que la componen el numero que le corresponden según el diccionario armado, para luego poder sumar esos valores.
Podrían, por favor, ayudarme?
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar un ejemplo de entrada y cómo debe quedar la salida? Por ejemplo, si entras: `Irlene`, ¿quieres de salida `983565` o cómo debe ser el formato?

Comment: El número lo obtienes de letas[i].

Answer (score 1):

Una solución corta y simple:

```
listaVocales = []
listaConsonantes = []
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
for letra in nombre:
    if letra in letas:
        if letra in "aeiou":
            listaVocales.append(letas[letra])
        else:
            listaConsonantes.append(letas[letra])
print(listaVocales, sum(listaVocales))
print(listaConsonantes, sum(listaConsonantes))
```

Usamos un `for` para recorrer el nombre letra por letra. Al preguntar si `letra` está en el diccionario `letas`, estamos validando que la letra sea una vocal o consonante, y no otra cosa.

Ya validada la letra, hay que distinguir si es consonante o vocal. La forma más fácil es usando `if letra in "aeiou":`.

En lugar de guardar la letra en la lista, voy a guardar directamente el valor asociado, que sale del diccionario.

Finalmente, imprimo la lista y la suma, usando la función `sum()`.

#### Demo

```
# -----Diccionario-----

letas = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "j": 2,
    "s": 2,
    "k": 2,
    "t": 3,
    "l": 3,
    "d": 3,
    "u": 4,
    "m": 4,
    "e": 5,
    "x": 5,
    "p": 5,
    "n": 6,
    "ñ": 6,
    "f": 6,
    "y": 6,
    "w": 7,
    "o": 7,
    "g": 7,
    "h": 8,
    "r": 8,
    "z": 8,
    "q": 9,
    "i": 9,
}

# -----Extraer vocales-----
listaVocales = []
listaConsonantes = []
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")
for letra in nombre:
    if letra in letas:
        if letra in "aeiou":
            listaVocales.append(letas[letra])
        else:
            listaConsonantes.append(letas[letra])
print(listaVocales, sum(listaVocales))
print(listaConsonantes, sum(listaConsonantes))
```

produce:

```
Ingrese su nombre: Juan Alberto 3°
[4, 1, 5, 7] 17
[6, 3, 1, 8, 3] 21

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ha comentado otro usuario, el valor lo tienes ya en el diccionario. Podrías hacer algo así:

```
#-----Comienzo-----

nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre: ")

vocales = "a, e, i, o, u"

letrasVocales = ""

consonantes = "b, c, d, f, g, h, j, k, l, m, n, ñ, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z"

letrasConsonantes = ""

#-----Diccionario-----

letas = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 1,
    "j": 2,
    "s": 2,
    "k": 2,
    "t": 3,
    "l": 3,
    "d": 3,
    "u": 4,
    "m": 4,
    "e": 5,
    "x": 5,
    "p": 5,
    "n": 6,
    "ñ": 6,
    "f": 6,
    "y": 6,
    "w": 7,
    "o": 7,
    "g": 7,
    "h": 8,
    "r": 8,
    "z": 8,
    "q": 9,
    "i": 9,
    }

#-----Extraer vocales-----

for i in nombre.lower():

    if i in vocales:
        letrasVocales += i

listaVocales = list (letrasVocales)

print (listaVocales)


#-----Extraer consonantes-----

for i in nombre.lower():

    if i in consonantes:
        letrasConsonantes += i

listaConsonantes = list (letrasConsonantes)

print (listaConsonantes)


#-----Recorrer las listas para reemplazar las letras por el numero del diccionario-----

valorVocales=[]

for i in listaVocales:
    valorVocales.append(letas[i])

print(valorVocales)
print(sum(valorVocales))

valorConsonantes=[]

for i in listaConsonantes:
    valorConsonantes.append(letas[i])

print(valorConsonantes)
print(sum(valorConsonantes))
```

En cualquier caso, tu código se puede simplificar bastante. Podrías dejarlo así:

```
nombre = input("Ingrese su nombre:")
vocales = "a, e, i, o, u"

#-----Diccionario-----

letras = {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "j": 2,
         "s": 2, "k": 2, "t": 3, "l": 3,
         "d": 3, "u": 4, "m": 4, "e": 5,
         "x": 5, "p": 5, "n": 6, "ñ": 6,
         "f": 6, "y": 6, "w": 7, "o": 7,
         "g": 7, "h": 8, "r": 8, "z": 8,
         "q": 9, "i": 9
        }

# Extraemos vocales y consonantes
listaVocales = []
listaConsonantes = []

for letra in nombre.lower():
    if letra in vocales:
        listaVocales.append(letra)
    else:
        listaConsonantes.append(letra)

#-----Recorrer las listas para reemplazar las letras por el numero del diccionario-----
valorVocales = [letras[letra] for letra in listaVocales]
valorConsonantes = [letras[letra] for letra in listaConsonantes]
print(listaVocales, valorVocales, sum(valorVocales))
print(listaConsonantes, valorConsonantes, sum(valorConsonantes))
```

Menos bucles y más cómodo de leer.

De igual manera, ten en cuenta que ninguno de los códigos podría manejar nombres con espacios en blanco (Juan Luis, por ejemplo) o nombres con tilde (María). Eso ya a tu elección, pero esto te puede guiar un poco.

```
Ingrese su nombre:Antonio
['a', 'o', 'i', 'o'] [1, 7, 9, 7] 24
['n', 't', 'n'] [6, 3, 6] 15
```

Answer (score 0):

acá te dejo una versión que soporta espacios vacios y otros.

```
import re

letras = {
    "a": 1,  "b": 1,  "c": 1,  "j": 2,  "s": 2,  "k": 2,  "t": 3,
    "l": 3,  "d": 3,  "u": 4,  "m": 4,  "e": 5,  "x": 5,  "p": 5,
    "n": 6,  "ñ": 6,  "f": 6,  "y": 6,  "w": 7,  "o": 7,  "g": 7,
    "h": 8,  "r": 8,  "z": 8,  "q": 9,  "i": 9,
}
listaVocales = []
listaConsonantes = []
valorVocales = 0
valorConsonantes = 0
nombre = "Armando Marcos"
for i in nombre.lower():
    if None != re.search( "[aeiou]", i ):
        listaVocales.append( i )
        valorVocales += letras.get( i )
    elif None != re.search("[a-z]", i ):
        listaConsonantes.append( i )
        valorConsonantes += letras.get( i )

print( f"Las vocales contenidas son: {listaVocales} y la suma de sus valores es {valorVocales}" )
print( f"Las consonantes contenidas son: {listaConsonantes} y la suma de sus valores es {valorConsonantes}" )
```

Como podrás ver, uso el módulo **re** para trabajar con expresiones regulares, que debes importar como en el ejemplo, especificamente uso la función **search**, que devuelve **None** si no encuentra coincidencia.
Dentro del primer **if**, se verifica si la letra es una vocal, de ser así, se entra al **if** y se le agrega a **listaVocales**, y a **valorVocales** le suma el valor devuelto por el diccionario **letras**.
El segundo **if**, hace lo propio con las consonantes.
Solo queda imprimir el resultado.
Puedes obtener más info sobre expresiones regulares en: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp.

Comment: `re.search("[aeiou]", i)` es *overkill* realmente. Basta con `if i in 'aeiou':`

Comment: @CandidMoe, no se me había ocurrido, supongo que como decidí usar regex, mi pobre cerebro quedo clavado ahí, gracias por "iluminarme".